# Xcode 7 Build failed with Error "OS X xib do not support target device type iPhone"

Tags: xcode7, ios9

My project is working well in XCode 6. However, when I build my project in xCode7 Beta, I see the error message below:

> OS X xib do not support target device type iPhone

Please help me how to solve this error.

Comment: Can you provide any more of an error log than the above error message? More information should allow someone to help you better with this issue.

Comment: I didn't find any other error logs, Error is showing in GDrive Library.  File name is GTMOAuthWindow.xib

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GTMOAuthWindow.xib file is using in GDriveLibrary for making Mac based Application.This is not essential for to make iOS application. I have deleted this class from my project, Then worked for me.
So if you are using any OS X xib in your iOS Application delete the file.